# Dividir autenticación en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una aplicación en Laravel que inicie el proceso que trae por defecto para autentifcarse

En el archivo "**LoginControler.php**" estoy rescribiendo el metodo "**login()**", en el cual estoy usando el metodo "**Auth::attempt()**" para validar los datos e iniciar la sesión confirmando que ya esta autentificado.

Mi pregunta es si existe un metodo que sirva unica y exclusivamente para generar la sesion validada sin validar los datos en la base de datos ya que voy a validar los datos de accesos mediante el consumo de un webservice externo, no deseo usar un plugin para login de redes sociales u otros.

Espero poder ser claro con mi duda.

Gracias

"**ACTUALIZADO 11 de Septiembre 2018**"

Decidí crear un Provider Personalizado en Laravel creando el archivo "**\app\Providers\RubyUserProvider.php**" se registro de manera exitosa en la aplicación para ser usado con el metodo "**Auth::attempt($credenciales)**" en mi archivo personalizado "**LoginController.php**", estoy re-escribiendo los siguientes métodos

"**retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)**" el cual lo uso para validar buscar y validar que el usuario y la contraseña existan en mi base devolviendo un objeto de tipo Authenticatable

"**validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, Array $credentials)**" Este metodo recibe el objeto de tipo Authenticatable y el array de las credenciales que ingresan en el formulario, y se compara que todo este correcto y regreso un true

Mi pregunta donde esta o donde debo rescribir para que se guarde los datos para guardar la sesión autentifiada para usar correctamente el metodo general "**$this->middleware('auth');**"

Fin de la actualización

Espero darme a entender

Comment: Existe un bundle para la autenticación a través de distintos servicios. Se llama HWIOAuthBundle. Lo interesante es que lo integras en tu aplicación y en lugar de utilizar los proveedores que te ofrece, puedes definir tu propio provider (en tu caso llamando a ese webservice)

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, conoces alguna forma que no sea el agregar un bundle

Answer (score 0):

Podrías generar la sesión con el helper `session()` de Laravel

```
public function autenticar(Request $request){
   if ($request->input('pin') === env('PIN')) {
      $request->session()->put('autenticado', time());
      return true;
   }
}
```

En tu función `handle` del custom Middleware que vayas a crear, podrías poner algo así:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!empty(session('autenticado'))) {
        $request->session()->put('autenticado', time());
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Aunque si deberías de estar generando alguna especie de token o algo para que la sesión sea más segura.

Comment: Deseo ocupar el sistema por defecto de Laravel para conservar el uso de todo lo referente a los helpers de Auth

Comment: @ManuelLunaSoto Entiendo, entonces me parece que necesitarías darle una checada a esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: Ya implemente un nuevo Provider, ya esta funcionando al momento de ser invocado por el metodo "Auth::attempt" en el Provider coloque codigo en los metodos "retrieveByCredentials y validateCredentials" pero no se en que metodo modificar para que se guarde la sesión de autentificado que se evalua con el metodo "$this->middleware('aut');"  no se si me explico

Comment: @ManuelLunaSoto Mm ¿podrías actualizar tu pregunta poniendo el código que añadiste por favor?

Comment: Listo ya lo actualice

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el middleware `auth` es un middleware que ya viene por defecto en laravel pero realmente no hace mucha cosa, una pregunta, después de que verificas tus credenciales, ¿qué te devuelve `Auth::check()` una vez autenticado tu usuario?

Comment: Precisamente necesito saber que metodo o propiedad debo modificar para que el middleware que trae por defecto Laravel funcione validando que esta autentificado para validar todas mis rutas para que solo sean vistas por el usuario que se autentifico con mis cambios

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con un custom middleware, ¿qué te devuelve `dd(Auth::check());` una vez autenticado tu usuario?

Comment: el `dd(Auth::check());` antes de ejecutar el metodo `Auth::attempt($credenciales)` da una respuesta false, al ejecutarlo despues de metodo me da un respuesta true esto supongo que indica que ya esta autenticado el problema es que cuando redirecciono a un controlador que tiene el `$this->middleware('auth');` me vuelve a solicitar el login por que me supongo que me falta un paso mas para completar el login en la sesion

Comment: @ManuelLunaSoto Lo que pasa es que el middleware por defecto trabaja con la autenticación propia de Laravel, crea un custom middleware `php artisan make:middleware NombreDelMiddleware` y dentro de la función `handle` haz tu condición `if(Auth::check())`... sigue los pasos para registrar un middleware aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Comment: De manera general entiendo asi el funcionamiento de la autenticación, Primero los guardias establecen la forma de como guardar la sesión despues los provider verifican si el usuario es valido en la base de datos y los middleware validan las reglas antes de mandar la respuesta al usuario, entonces ya personalice solo el provider para indicarle al guardia que existe el usuario, el tema es que el guardia no esta guardando la sesión correctamente ya que el middleware de manera predeterminada no lo esta logrando validar

Comment: Si, los middleware validan, pero tú puedes crear tu propio middleware, lo qué pasa es que usando el middleware “auth” no creo que te funcione, por eso te digo que crees tu propio middleware con el comando artisan